# How to select the same columns from all rows?

Tags: php, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a table with 50 rows and like 10 columns each. One of the columns is called "phpclass" and holds string.
The actual string entry can be unique, but it can also be the same over different rows, i.e. course of the query.

I would like to query the table and receive something along the lines of hits with similar value in that "phpclass" columns.

i.E.

```
$resultA = ["Orion", "Nova", "Alpha"];
$resultB = [1, 4, 3];
```

Can someone help me create a query for this ?

Comment: We were all noobs once, eh?

Comment: No doubt @OllieJones. It would have been nice to have seen some effort though.

Comment: The reason that you're getting downvotes @C.Finke is because you didn't show any effort at all :) I asked the question so that I could learn your level of knowledge which would help me to determine how best to respond to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do a query with `GROUP BY`, something like this:

```
SELECT   phpclass, COUNT(*) occurences
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY phpclass
```

Then you could use something like `mysqli_fetch_all` to retrieve all the rows, which would give you the following structure:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$result = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
// $result will be like:
// Array(
//   Array("phpclass" => "Orion", "occurrences" => 1),
//   Array("phpclass" => "Nova", "occurrences" => 4),
//   Array("phpclass" => "Alpha", "occurrences" => 5)
// );
$resultA = array_column($result, "phpclass");
$resultB = array_column($result, "occurrences");
print_r ($resultA);
print_r ($resultB);
```

Output will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Orion
    [1] => Nova
    [2] => Alpha
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want

```
 SELECT phpclass, COUNT(*) count
   FROM table
  GROUP BY phpclass
```

This will give you back the rows

```
 Orion    1
 Nova     4
 Alpha    5
```

showing how many rows have the values `Orion` etc. (not necessarily in that order).